# NSFetchRequest Collection.first Always Returning Entity from Empty Store

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the following code that always returns an instance of `Member`, when it should be returning `nil`. No matter what I input for `username`, and no matter how many times I delete the app from the simulator, the `throw` is always triggered from the `create` function.

```swift
class MemberViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...

    init(_ entity: Member? = nil) {
        self.entity = entity
    }

    init(name: String, username: String, password: String, age: String?, role: String, admin: Bool, imageName: String, imageTint: String) {
        let context = Self.container.viewContext
        self.entity = Member(context: context)

        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.age = age ?? ""
        self.role = role
        self.admin = admin
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.imageTint = imageTint
    }

    func create() throws -> Void {
        let context = Self.container.viewContext

        if entity!.username != nil {
            if try Self.fetch(username: entity!.username!) != nil {
                throw MemberError.UserExists(username: entity!.username!)
            }

            if context.hasChanges {
                try context.save()
            }
        }
    }

    static private func fetch(username: String) throws -> Member? {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Member> = Member.fetchRequest()
        let context = Self.container.viewContext

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username[c] == %@", username)
        return try? context.fetch(fetchRequest).first
    }

    ...
}

extension MemberViewModel {
    public enum MemberError: Error {
        case UserExists(username: String)
    }
}
```

The calling code looks like:

```swift
extension MemberView {
    func save() -> Void {
        if (name.isEmpty) {
            nameError = "A name must be provided to continue"
        }

        if (username.isEmpty) {
            usernameError = "A username or email must be provided"
        }

        if (nameError != nil || usernameError != nil) {
            return
        }

        do {
            let mvm = MemberViewModel(name: name, username: username, password: password, age: age, role: role, admin: admin, imageName: AVATARS[selectedImage], imageTint: selectedTint)
            try mvm.create()

            page = nil
        } catch MemberViewModel.MemberError.UserExists(let username) {
            usernameError = "The username \(username) is already taken"
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens in the constructor of MemberViewModel?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I added in the initializers.

Comment: Ugh. I feel a little foolish. Turns out that NSFetchRequest will return unsaved records matching the NSPredicate, so I need to check uniqueness before creating the new Member entity in the initializer.

Comment: `self.entity = Member(context: context)`, here you are creating a new object in your managed object context which is a bad design. You shouldn’t create it before all validations and such are done and you are actually ready to store the object. Anyway , you never set the username attribute on `entity` so the condition `if entity!.username != nil` should always fail and no error would then be thrown so there is clearly some other information missing from the question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Good advice about validation before creation!